# "Performance car" en español

Tags: traducción

¿Cuál es el término correcto para "performance car" en español? Esos autos que modifican o que construyen especialmente para carreras.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen "automóvil" or "coche de alto rendimiento", but we generally use "coche de carreras" for all cars used in sports events.

That what I'll say at least, but I admit I'm not very into cars.

Answer (score 2):

Un *performance car* no es un coche de carreras; usaríamos esa expresión (al menos, en España) para los coches fabricados exclusivamente para la competición, como los fórmula 1, lo que no es el caso. Para un *performance car* usaríamos la palabra *deportivo*, al menos en España (no *coche deportivo*; simplemente, un *performance car* sería *un deportivo*).

Answer (score 0):

Se puede decir "**coche de carreras**" (me suena un poco informal) o "**coche de competición**". Y por supuesto en América Latina se utilizaría "carro" o "auto" en lugar de "coche" en ambos casos.